# Docker: Write Permission on directory, but user cannot write

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, chmod, docker-machine

I have a SLES11 docker image that I run using docker-machine (virtualbox VM) on OS X.

It shows odd behaviour when it comes to file permissions.
The Volume in question is not mounted via '-v', it is provided by the image (not persistent or explicitly shared with the host OS)

Inside the docker image I run apache2 as wwwrun:www
As user `wwwrun:www`, it is not possible to touch a file inside `/srv/www/htdocs/foo/bar`

The chmod on `bar` is `777` and it is owned by `wwwrun:www`.
Creating files on the volume is possible. user `wwwrun` can touch files `foo`, user `root` can touch files in the problematic `bar` directory.

What other reasons could there be that prevent write access for user wwwrun?

Comment: Is it a volume or a host bind-mount?

Comment: It is not mounted (i.e. docker run without -v argument), the folder is on the non persistent file system provided by the SLES base image.